# MySQL left join count with condition

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause

I have two tables:

1. cc_videos with fields: id, challenge_id, upload_date, owner_id
2. cc_video_votes with fields id, video_id, vote_date

Field "id" in "cc_videos" corresponds to a field "video_id" in "cc_video_votes" and I have a statement like this:

```
SELECT cc_videos.*, COUNT(video_id) AS votes_count
FROM cc_videos LEFT JOIN cc_video_votes
ON cc_videos.id = cc_video_votes.video_id
GROUP BY cc_videos.id
ORDER BY votes_count desc
```

Now this works OK - lists ALL VIDEOS sorted by videos with highest vote rate first. Now i want to put condition to list only videos from "cc_videos" WHERE challenge_id matches variable "$challenge_id", but when I put condition like this it returns 0 results:

```
SELECT cc_videos.*, COUNT(video_id) AS votes_count
FROM cc_videos WHERE challenge_id = "$challenge_id"
LEFT JOIN cc_video_votes
ON cc_videos.id = cc_video_votes.video_id
GROUP BY cc_videos.id
ORDER BY votes_count desc
```

Am I using WHERE clause correctly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you are not.

```
SELECT cc_videos.*, COUNT(video_id) AS votes_count
FROM cc_videos 
LEFT JOIN cc_video_votes
ON cc_videos.id = cc_video_votes.video_id
WHERE cc_videos.challenge_id = "$challenge_id"
GROUP BY cc_videos.id
ORDER BY votes_count desc
```

`WHERE` syntax should stay in clauses, [**check documentation here**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to:

```
SELECT cc_videos.*,
       Count(video_id) AS votes_count
FROM   cc_videos
       LEFT JOIN cc_video_votes
              ON cc_videos.id = cc_video_votes.video_id
WHERE  cc_videos.challenge_id = "$challenge_id"
GROUP  BY cc_videos.id
ORDER  BY votes_count DESC
```